# CakePHP 3 - how to call XMLWriter()

Tags: xml, cakephp

For the purposes of web application, I use an external php script written in plain PHP code.
In class I call the following functions:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
```

By calling these functions I get the error:

```
Error: Class 'App\Lib\XMLWriter' not found
File /root/src/Lib/Fiscalization.php
Line: 201
```

What to do to the above functions are called without problems?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
$writer = new \XMLWriter();